# Create a VBA Message Box Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

So, this should be fairly easy to implement, but I am unable to get the message box to display.

Context - this is for an estimation tool - if the user enters a value for a particular cell that is less than a minimum threshold, I want to bring up a message box to let them know that's not a valid entry.

The cell I am referring to is named (let's just say `TEST`). Its location is on the `UI` tab (1 of 4 tabs in the workbook) is row 47, column 17.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
Sub UI Alerts()
    If Cells(47, 17) < "1000" Then
        MsgBox ("Minimum Value is 1000")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

Similarly, with the named cell

```
Sub UI Alerts()
    If ("TEST").value < "1000" Then
        MsgBox ("Minimum Value is 1000")
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

I have set this up in the VBA module that corresponds to the UI tab, so I shouldn't have to reference the sheet. Any idea why the message box isn't displaying? Is it possible to automatically display a message box based on a cell value?

Thanks.

Comment: Why VBA? Why not Data Validation?

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249

Comment: `("TEST")` is a string literal with redundant parentheses, it doesn't have a `.Value` member. Did you mean `ThisWorkbook.Names("TEST").RefersToRange.Value`?

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a specific reason we need this to be a macro, it sounds like standard data validation would work for you here. Try this: select the cell you want the rules applied to, then on the ribbon/toolbar find Data > Data Validation. You can require a whole number greater than 1,000 (or a value in another cell), display a comment box with instructions when the user selects the cell, and an error message if an invalid number is entered.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Change event within the worksheet. Below is a sample code that should work with your named range. At any rate, it should show you how to do so.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("TEST").Address Then
        If Range("TEST").Value < 1000 Then
            MsgBox ("Minimum Value is 1000")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add your code to the Worksheet "Change" event.

Right now, you have code but it never gets called.

Comment: This is more like a comment and not an answer :)

Comment: How is this not an answer? It explains specifically why it didn't work and what to do to make it work.